# Decrypt SSL Data in wireshark

Tags: linux, ubuntu, wireshark

In all the tutorials which I saw in web, they pointed me to add key file in

`Edit->Prefereces->Protocols->SSL->SSL key file`

but there is no such `SSL key file` in version I use.

Can somebody guide how to decrypt SSL Traffic in wireshark 1.12.4 ?

Answer (score -2):

It does not depend on the version of wireshark, but on the SSL lib it was compiled against.

In order to use it, you need to have a wireshark that was compiled using GnuTLS rather than OpenSSL or bsafe.

Comment: This is off topic, as it is not about programming, and should probably be on Super User.